# (Android )Keep getting errors on SQL Statement

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm having real trouble creating a table in my android application.

here are my error's :

```
06-21 23:29:58.490: E/SQLiteLog(19571): (1) near "index": syntax error
06-21 23:29:58.820: E/InfiniDatabase(19571): Creating Index Table Failed
06-21 23:29:58.820: E/InfiniDatabase(19571): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "index": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE index (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
```

This is a "testing" statement I'm using as my full statement just isn't playing ball. I am useless with SQL - is it me or the computer?

Here's the Java snippet:

```
//used to create are initial index table...
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    Log.d(TAG_NAME, "Now Creating Index Table");
    try{
        final String INDEX_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + INDEX_TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + 
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" + ")";

        db.execSQL(INDEX_TABLE_CREATE);

        Log.d(TAG_NAME,"Created New Index Table");
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG_NAME, "Creating Index Table Failed", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the name "index" as a name for your table since it is a keyword in sqlite 
please refere to this link http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Yeah, just figured this out myself to! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a semi-colons

```
final String INDEX_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + INDEX_TABLE_NAME +
            " (" + 
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" + ");";
```

Comment: And that to.. some examples don't use. Isn't it optional?